# How to prevent duplicate commits in git merge?

Tags: git

I have two branches master and branch-1.
branch-1 is from master, and at some point it has a commit that's cherry-picked from a particular commit in master.

When I merge branch-1 back to master, the cherry-picked commit shows up, causing the git log to show two commits in master with identical changes.  How do I make it so master only has one commit SHA for that change?

Comment: You really shouldn't need to worry about that. While the commit may show up in the history twice, that is legitimate, because the change entered the current code via two different routes. However, the effects of the change will only be applied once, and `git` is smart enough to sort that out - when it does the merge, it effectively sees that the change from `branch-1` has already been applied, and so it doesn't need to be applied again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that without some history rewrite. If you are ok to rewrite the history of `branch-1` before merging it to `master`, you can do squash merge or rebase interactive.

With the squash merge you do `git checkout master; git merge --squash branch-1` and get a one bit squashed commit of all the changes in `branch-1`.

Rebase will allow you to replay the history of the `branch-1` on top of `master`. As the cherry-picked commit is already present there, you may simply comment it out if in the interactive mode.